# crear trigger para cambiar un campo

Tags: sql, trigger

tengo una tabla que me sirve para mandar una publicidad a clientes, en esta tabla tengo un campo que se llama email, necesito que un trigger haga el cambio después de que se inserte un registro de un cliente, que verifique que ese campo en particular que es email, si eta null lo ponga en vació,

Comment: En qué motor quieres realizar esto? la sintaxis del trigger suele variar entre un motor y otro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no entendí mal, la idea es que cuando se inserta un registro con email en NULL se lo convierta en un string vacío, no?  Si es así, para crear un trigger como ese en SQL Server deberías hacer esto:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[NombreTrigger]
   ON [dbo].[miTabla]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE miTabla
    SET email = ''
    WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM inserted WHERE email IS NULL)

END
```

En la tabla temporal "inserted" están los datos del registro insertado, y ahí nos fijamos si email es nulo.

Espero se entienda.

¡Suerte!

Comment: En una inserción masiva, digamos de 1000 filas, donde solo una trae el email en null, este trigger dejará a todas con un email vacío.

Comment: Para nada, fijate que antes del UPDATE hay un IF que pregunta si la fila insertada tiene NULL en el campo email:
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE email IS NULL)...

Comment: es lo que digo. Si uno o más registros traen null, tu update deja a todos los insertados con el email con una cadena vacía. Estás cometiendo el error de asumir que solamente se inserta un registro por vez, pero hay varias maneras de hacer un insert de muchos registros a la vez, cada uno con su propio email.

Comment: Ahí modifiqué el trigger para que funcione como decís.

Comment: ¿Te funcionó con este trigger?

Comment: efectivamente eso es lo que necesito hacer, muchas gracias, lo probare y daré retro al resultad, muchas gracias

Comment: funciono y no, te explica, si cambia el email, pero me dice desarrollo que lo que necesita es primero validar  el campo de acuerdo a un grupo de clientes que se acaban de registrar, si este campo es nulo, ponerlo vació, y después ejecutar el trigger de insert, espero haber explicado correctamente

Comment: No entiendo lo de la "validación de acuerdo a un grupo de clientes".  Te recomiendo que crees una nueva pregunta detallando esta nueva información.

Comment: mira te paso lo que tengo ya trabajando, es un triguer que hace una función clara, después de insertar hace una copia y la manda a otra tabla, lo que me pide programación es que en ese trigger meta primero una validación  donde el campo emai si viene null lo cambie a vacia

Comment: INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbaPerfildelHuesped_Audit]
([idhuesped],[idtitulo],[nombres],[apellidopaterno],[apellidomaterno],[direccion],[ciudad],[codigopostal],[idestado],[cuenta],[ididioma],[telefono],[idpais],[idvip],[idagencia],[idcompania],[puesto],[idgrupo],[idmayorista],[email],[curp],[rfc],[fechadenacimiento],[saludoalhuesped],[idcodigodemercado],[ultimavisita],[ultimatarifa],[ultimahabitacion],[totaldenoches],[totaldevisitas],[totaldecancelaciones],[totaldenoshow],[totaldeingresos],[usualta],[fechaalta],[usumodi],[fechamodi],[userid],[idresortcom],[comentario],

Comment: [comentariopref],AuditDataState,AuditDMLAction,AuditUser,AuditDateTime,UpdateColumns)
SELECT CONVERT(numeric,[idhuesped]) as [idhuesped],[idtitulo],[nombres],[apellidopaterno],[apellidomaterno],[direccion],[ciudad],[codigopostal],[idestado],[cuenta],[ididioma],[telefono],[idpais],[idvip],[idagencia],[idcompania],

Comment: [puesto],[idgrupo],[idmayorista],[email],[curp],[rfc],[fechadenacimiento],[saludoalhuesped],[idcodigodemercado],[ultimavisita],[ultimatarifa],[ultimahabitacion],[totaldenoches],[totaldevisitas],[totaldecancelaciones],[totaldenoshow],[totaldeingresos],[usualta],[fechaalta],[usumodi],[fechamodi],[userid],[idresortcom],[comentario],[comentariopref],'New','Insert',SUSER_SNAME(),getdate(),''  FROM INSERTED 
l

Comment: es todo eso, de un solo movimiento,, espero me entiendas, tengo un grupo de clientes que llega el día de hoy, de todos esos clientes que llegan se registran, ese grupo de clientes es a los que necesito validar que tengan email, si no que quede en espacio vació

Comment: Disculpa, pero no se entiende nada.  Por favor crea una nueva pregunta y pon ahí el código para que podamos verlo y ayudarte.  Saludos.

Comment: lo arregle haciendo un job, en este job hago el update que platicamos al principio